# Tool 'dotnet-try' failed to install

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-tool

Trying to install [dotnet-try](https://github.com/dotnet/try) global tool from the command prompt on Windows by running `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-try`  but failed with the following error.

> Failed to create shell shim for tool 'dotnet-try': Command 'dotnet-try' conflicts with an existing command from another tool.
> Tool 'dotnet-try' failed to install.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are the latest commands to ***install, uninstall*** and ***update*** `dotnet-try`

**To Install**

```
> dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.dotnet-try
```

**To Uninstall**

```
> dotnet tool uninstall -g Microsoft.dotnet-try
```

**To Update**

```
> dotnet tool update -g Microsoft.dotnet-try
```